# How can I fix this Pythagorean Triplet program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythagorean

```
import sys

def pythTrue(a,b,c):
    (A,B,C) = (a*a,b*b,c*c)
    if A + B == C or B + C == A or A + C == B:
        return True

def smallestTrip(a,b,c):
    if pythTrue(a,b,c) == True:
        if (a+b+c)%12 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def tuplePyth(n):
    list_=[]
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(1, n):
            for z in range (1, n):
                if x+y+z<=n:
                    if smallestTrip(x, y, z)==False:
                        list_.append([x,y,z])
    print (list_)

tuplePyth(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

> Pythagorean triplets are sets of 3 positive integers a, b, c
>   satisfying the relationship a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> =
>   c<sup>2</sup>. The smallest and best-known Pythagorean triple is
>   (a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5). Write a program that reads a command line
>   argument n and prints to the screen all Pythagorean triplets whose sum
>   is less than n (i.e., a+b+c < n) and that are not multiple of the (3,
>   4, 5) triplet. Your program will represent triplets as 3-tuples, and
>   should consist of three functions:
>
> - a function that takes in a tuple
>     and returns a boolean indicating whether the Pythagorean relationship holds or not.
> - a function that takes in a tuple and returns
>     a boolean indicating whether a triplet is a multiple of the smallest
>     triplet or not.
> - a function that takes in an integer n and generates
>     the Pythagorean triplets as specified above. The function should
>     return a list of tuples.
>
> The main portion of your program pythagore.py will read in the command
>   line input, call the last function described above, and print the
>   results one triplet per line.

My problem is that I am getting the same combination in different
orders for example: (5,12,13),(13,12,5)...etc

Comment: Off-topic perhaps, but I don't think the `if (a+b+c)%12 == 0:` works in general because AFAIK there's no reason that the sum of the three numbers being a multiple of `12` indicates that they're the smallest triplet.

Comment: Of course it does if they already satisfy being pythagorean triplets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're short on logic in your main routine.  There is nothing to enforce that the triple comes in only one order: your `x` and `y` are interchangeable, and you guarantee that you'll check both.

Instead, force `x < y` with your loop limits, and then make sure you stop when the value of `y` or `z` gets too large to be viable.  Note that this gets rid of your check for the sum of the three.

```
def tuplePyth(n):
    list_=[]
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(1, n):
            for z in range (1, n):
                if x+y+z<=n:
                    if smallestTrip(x, y, z)==False:
                        list_.append([x,y,z])
    print (list_)
```

Instead:

```
def tuplePyth(n):
    list_=[]
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(x + 1, (n - x) // 2):
            for z in range (y + 1, n - x - y):
                if smallestTrip(x, y, z)==False:
                    list_.append([x,y,z])
    print (list_)
```

Output with n=100:

```
[[5, 12, 13], [7, 24, 25], [8, 15, 17], [9, 40, 41], [15, 36, 39], [16, 30, 34], [20, 21, 29]]
```

Note that you still have a problem with `smallestTrip`: your check is not logically equivalent to "smallest triple".  Instead, check that the three numbers are relatively prime.  Since Stack Overflow allows only one question per posting, and the problem is readily researched on line, I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to keep track of the ones aleady found and add checks to avoid repeating them. The following uses a `set` to store the ones already produced and sorts the the elements in each triple so that their order doesn't matter.

```
def tuplePyth(n):
    list_=[]
    seen = set()
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(1, n):
            for z in range (1, n):
                if tuple(sorted((x,y,z))) not in seen:
                    if x+y+z <= n:
                        if smallestTrip(x, y, z) == False:
                            list_.append([x,y,z])
                    seen.add((x,y,z))
    print (list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools:

```
 import itertools.combinations_with_replacement as cwr
 list_ = [triple for triple in cwr(range(n),3) if sum(triple)<n and not smallestTrip(triple)]
```

You can also force the numbers to be in order with the limits. Also, you can simplify finding a,b, c by realizing that if we define a to be the smallest number, then it must be smaller than n/3 (b and c will both be at least as large as a, so if a were larger than n/3, then the sum of a, b, and c would be more than n). Similarly, b must be smaller than n/2. Once you've found all the combinations of a and b, you can find all the c that are larger than b and smaller than n-a-b.

```
list_=[]
for x in range(1, n//3):
    for y in range(x+1, n//2):
        for z in range (x+y+1, n-x-y):
                if not smallestTrip(x, y, z):
                    list_.append([x,y,z])
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the three numbers are never the same you can just change the second and the third range from (1,n) to (x+1,n) and (y+1,n) correspondingly.